# How can I programmatically alter/replace a StoryBoard in a template?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, storyboard

I'm having a heck of a time figuring out how to alter one property of a Storyboard in my WPF window.

My window has an animation that reduces the size of window with kind of a "roll up" animation.  Depending on some condition (whether a certain prop is set), we want the window to be a little longer to fit an extra item.

I've been using this.FindResource() to grab elements, that's no problem.  But of course, the Storyboard is frozen, and the DoubleAnimations contained in it are frozen, so I can't change anything.

So I figure, fine, I'll just swap out the entire Storyboard.

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
    <Trigger.ExitActions>
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ToolbarCollapse_NoIB}" />
    </Trigger.ExitActions>
</Trigger>
```

I'm thinking that, programmatically, I can get in the code-behind and change that trigger to use ToolbarCollapse_YesIB.

In that attempt, I can get this far:

```
var tbTemplate = (ControlTemplate)this.FindResource("ToolbarTemplate");
var newStoryboard = (Storyboard)this.FindResource("ToolbarCollapse_YesIB");
tbTemplate.Triggers[2].ExitActions[0] = ??? needs to be a TriggerAction
```

And here's where I'm stuck.  How do I create a TriggerAction for that Storyboard?  The constructor doesn't really lend itself to this, nor the methods.

The docs for these classes lead me to think I'm way off track.

Can anyone help me either make this approach work, or clue me into another approach that would work better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution using an alternate method.  Seems like it might be a bit hacky, but it works.

I created two storyboards, `ToolbarCollapse_YesIB` and `ToolbarCollapse_NoIB`.  They only differ by the height property.

Then I replaced my original question's Trigger above with two MultiTriggers:

```
<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
        <Condition Property="MinHeight"
                   Value="{StaticResource ToolbarCollapsedHeight_YesIB}"/>
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ToolbarCollapse_YesIB}" />
    </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
</MultiTrigger>

<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
        <Condition Property="MinHeight"
                   Value="{StaticResource ToolbarCollapsedHeight_NoIB}"/>
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ToolbarCollapse_NoIB}" />
    </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
</MultiTrigger>
```

I use my object's constructor to set `MinHeight`.  Depending on presence of my IB field, I set `MinHeight` to `ToolbarCollapsedHeight_YesIB` or `_NoIB`.

So now if `MinHeight=(my YesIB size)`, one storyboard is active.  If `MinHeight=(my NoIB size)`, the other storyboard is active.

(I actually have another pair of `ToolbarExpand_YesIB/NoIB` templates, assigned to `MultiTrigger.EnterActions` in the above triggers, but I left them out for brevity.)

This was a genuine pain in the butt.  I hope this helps other people who find similar situations.